# How do I go about implementing add business hours to my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the final display on view page will be something like:

> Mon - Fri: 9:00am - 5:00pm
>
> Sat: 9:00am - 3:00pm
>
> Sun: Close

And will automatically display depending on what the day is something like:

> Now Open 9:00am - 5:00pm

What is my approach on this? The only solution I can think of now is to add columns (mon, tue, wed...sun, opening_time, closing_time) to my existing model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any columns to your model for this. You can simply do this in your views

```
Time.now.utc.wday
```

which will give you a value from `0-6` where (0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc). So conditionally you can change the time if

```
Time.now.utc.wday == 0
```

display `close` and so on.